# Get user data in package controller in Concrete 5.7

Tags: concrete5

I know how to get it in the view:

```
$u = new User();
$u->isLoggedIn();
```

How about the controller?

```
Error: Class 'Concrete\Package\PageRedirect\User' not found
```

I am using C5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/users-groups/reading-data-existing-users

`use Concrete\Core\User\User;` or `use User`.